# Elixir/Phoenix umbrella app with two apps and access through subdomain mapped through reverse proxy with nginx

Tags: nginx, elixir, reverse-proxy, phoenix-framework

It's several hours I'm trying but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm on a server with ubuntu 16.04, I have an umbrella app with two apps in it, which I would like to map to frontend.example.com and backend.example.com. On the DNS I have a wildcard for the whole domain (*.example.com + @.example.com). An additional issue is that one of them has to be on HTTPS,so I have the following onstart:

```
09:45:38.013 [info] Running FrontendWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:91
09:45:38.055 [info] Running FrontendWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using https://0.0.0.0:445
09:45:38.199 [info] Running BackendWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:90
```

I would like Frontend to be mapped to frontend.example.com and the like for the second one. I have this servers.conf under /etc/nginx/conf.d:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name backend.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:90;
            ...
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name frontend.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:91;
            ...
    }

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name frontend.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:445;
            ...
    }
```

Is there something missing? It's not really working, only the backend redirect partially works.

EDIT: Should I put something in sites-available too? or the conf file is enough?

Comment: Does it work when you add a trailing slash `/` to the url in `proxy_pass`? Like: `proxy_pass http://localhost:90/;`.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: well, when I type frontend.example.com or backend.example.com it just gets stuck.

Comment: Also, when I tried to add an https endpoint to the backend, making the suitable changes to the nginx conf, none of them works really. I think there's something wrong with the elixir configuration but I have no idea what to try anymore.

Comment: Have you checked your nginx logs?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't say anything.

Comment: You could run all your apps on HTTP and make nginx proxy do the HTTPS for you. You redirect to http:// on port 443, which is HTTPS in your application. So that's wrong for sure.

Comment: I tried to https, doesn't change anything